# Disable and enable actionButton() by pushing another actionButton() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below with 2 `actionButton()`. I want when I press `Datatable` the `Datatable2` to be disabled and when I click again on `Datatable` the `Datatable2` to be available for pressing again.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc","Datatable"),
      actionButton("exc2","Datatable2")
    ),
    mainPanel( 
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
 
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really straightforward if you use the `toggleState()` function from the shinyjs package.

The help for that function gives you an extremely similar situation. In your case:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), #this activates shinyjs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc","Datatable"),
      actionButton("exc2","Datatable2")
    ),
    mainPanel( 
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    toggleState("exc2") #identify the element to toggle between active/inactive
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```